# Getting Values from JSON Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to retrieve values from an array that I get from a JSON web request. But I can't get the valueForKey function to work so I can apply the String to a label. The example below searches Apples API for software. As a test, I want to be able to apply the "trackName" key to a UILabel, but everything I try, I either crash, or return nil.

Here is my code

```
func searchFunction(searchQuery: NSString) {
    var url : NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString("https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(searchQuery)&media=software")
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:url)
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task : NSURLSessionDataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

        var newdata : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

        var info : NSArray =  newdata.valueForKey("results") as NSArray

        var name: String? = info.valueForKey("trackName") as? String // Returns nil
        println(name)//Returns nil


        var name2 : NSString = info.valueForKey("trackName") as NSString //Crashes
        println(name2) //Crashes

        });


    task.resume()
    println("Resumed")

}
```

The comments next to the variables explains what happens with each one. Can someone explain how I can convert the valueForKey("trackName") to a string that can be applied to a label?

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Info is an array, so check with:

```
var name: String? = info[0].valueForKey("trackName") as? String
var name: String? = info[0].valueForKey("trackName") as? NSString
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Why do I need to specify the index, "0"? In Objective-C I could use a way similar to what I have and it would spit out a string.