# Get string from JSON Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I need to get string from the `JSON Array` which is a response from the external server. This is my code:

```
if let dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,error: &parsingError) as NSDictionary?{

    var info : NSArray = dictionary.valueForKey("data") as NSArray
    var names: String? = info[0].valueForKey("firstname") as? String

    println("name ++\(names)")

}
```

It's compiling but when I execute, not running I got as

> thread 8:exc_bad_access (code=2 ..

This is `Dictonary` coming from server side

```
{
 data =     {
     Id = 55;
     firstName = fgg;
     gender = 1;
 };
 success = 1; }
```

I followed thread without success : [Getting Values from JSON Array in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074042/getting-values-from-json-array-in-swift)

Can anyone help me to get this string out? I cannot find out the error I have done here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its not an array, its a dictionary.

Comment: Try this `var info : NSDictionary = dictionary.valueForKey("data") as NSDictionary
   var names: String? = info["firstName"] as? String

    println("name ++\(names)")`

Comment: please let me know if any issue occur Thanks!

Comment: @MuseerAnsari Thanks. It's working but print with "Optional". Can you add this as a answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Yes just copy and paste my answer (given below) i have updated and if working then please upvote Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if let dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,error: &parsingError) as NSDictionary?{

    var info : NSDictionary = dictionary.valueForKey("data") as! NSDictionary 
    var names: String? = info["firstName"] as? String 
    println("name ++\(names!)")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let dataId = response.value(forKeyPath: "data.id") as! NSNumber
```

I usually do this if am not up to deserialization.

Comment: Thanks for you support.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
do
{
 let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
}
catch _{}

let data      = json["data"] as! NSDictionary
let firstName = data["firstName"]
```

Comment: Thanks for you support.